# Apply select2 functionality to all select boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a `div` with dynamic select boxes like the following:

```
<div id="boxes">
 <select name="item[]"><option></option></select>
 <select name="item[]"><option></option></select>
 <select name="item[]"><option></option></select>
 ...
 ...
 ...
</div>
```

I want to apply the select2 to all of them but I don't know how to this, your suggestion will appreciate me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
$('#boxes select').select2({
  // ...
})
```

Comment: It applied the style when I click on first select box it works fine but the others are not open and not working

Comment: Not possible. You have something else on your side. The question in its current form is 100% answered with what I posted ([proof](http://plnkr.co/edit/88CPZVCWNlFhVfCEIxbZ?p=preview)). If it doesn't work it means that you mess up something else, but it's not possible to guess unless you provide more details.

Comment: Cool, glad you found it.

Comment: Could you please take a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671098/jquery-select2-on-specific-div-after-ajax-call-is-very-slow ?